# How to remove top margin BODY

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this set up

```
.image-head {
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/1920x1080);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    #text-align: center;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rjyhrn8b/) is my code in full.

How do I remove the top margin?

Comment: perhaps the problem is with the `html` element ... give that a margin/padding of zero too

Comment: @JaromandaX  no it's not. It the "media_bar" class. See my answer

Comment: ther is no "media_bar" class in the question

Comment: There is a fiddle...

Comment: Relevant code should be posted in the question itself. Answers are about a media bar that doesn't exist in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site to review your problem. Links to demos are great but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: He thought the problem was in the the "body" tag. Looking from his perspective, the code is relevant.

Comment: @ceferrari - That's why we ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So that the actual problem is in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
.media_bar {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjyhrn8b/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is a margin added by the `ul` element with class `"media_bar"`.Below is the snapshot.

Set the `margin-top:0` in this class
[image: DOM Snaphot]